# Mpabox GL Places Layer Hovering Offset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I have set up a map with markers and popups when clicking on those markers.
My issue is that the clickable part of the marker is waaaaaaay below the marker and its text, so I can click it from very awkwards positions. Any ideas how to set or change that part of the marker?

(I couldn't make a codepen work but I share here a diagram)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JFtq.jpg)

It's fairly obvious to picture, the red zon is the part where nothing happens and where I would like to extend the 'clickability' of the point.

The green part is the clickable part and as you can see it's very long under the point.

The blue point is more or less where the point is actually.

This is the code for generating the popup.

```
map.loadImage(
    "http://localhost/healing-hub/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Map-marker.png",
    function (error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      map.addImage("hh-marker", image);
      map.addSource("point", {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [{
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [0, 0],
            },
          }, ],
        },
      });

      map.addLayer({
        id: "places",
        type: "symbol",
        source: {
          type: "geojson",
          data: {
            type: "FeatureCollection",
            features: featureCollection,
          },
        },
        layout: {
          "icon-image": "hh-marker",
          "icon-size": .45,
          "icon-anchor": 'bottom',
          "icon-offset": [0, 0],
          "text-field": "{title}",
          "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
          "text-offset": [0, 0],
          "text-anchor": "top",
        },
        paint: {
          "icon-translate": [0, 0],
        }
      });
    }
  );
```

I have tried icon-anchor, icon-translate, but that moves only the image not the clickable part.

Icon-offset does diplace that part it it makes it really awkward and doesn't work properly for pointin visually the location. Also there I discovered playing with icon-anchor and icon translate there are two separate clicking areas actually, one under the image and one under the title.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please include an example in a codepen so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Hey I couldn' make a codepen work so I added an image, hope that helps.

Comment: A codepen would be much better. It lets people verify that the problem is actually the way you describe it, inspect the environment for clues, and try things to fix it.

Comment: I created a codepen for you. I don't see the problem you describe at all. https://codepen.io/stevebennett/pen/XWdRPEr My best guess is that your marker image contains a lot of transparent area at the bottom or something.